# R 3.0.2 on Mavericks can't install.packages()

Tags: r, clang, osx-mavericks

I've updated to R 3.0.2 with Homebrew and certain packages don't install.

```
> install.packages('colorspace')
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/colorspace_1.2-4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 242791 bytes (237 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 237 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘colorspace’ ...
** package ‘colorspace’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.0.2/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC   -c colorspace.c -o colorspace.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/lib -o colorspace.so colorspace.o -F/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.0.2/R.framework/.. -framework R -lintl -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: library not found for -lintl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [colorspace.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘colorspace’
* removing ‘/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.0.2/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/colorspace’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘colorspace’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/8w/6_2hydbn0b16kzj3llxnx2480000gp/T/RtmpYoGAWp/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370363/link-error-installing-rcpp-library-not-found-for-lintl seems to suggest `brew install gettext` or `brew reinstall gettext`

Comment: Try searching SO with the `R` tag for "Mavericks" . There are several useful answers.  Or you could search the r-sig-mac archives, as Simon has weighed in on `clang` and Mavericks as well.

Comment: Thanks both, neither were successful. In the end I installed R w/out homebrew and it's working fine.